# How do I use Mockito mock an afterPropertiesSet method that implements an InitializingBean

Tags: mockito, junit4, spring-test

Now I have some other library beans that implement initializingBeans and add some time-consuming methods, but I don't want to actually execute them, I need the Spring environment, but this bean I can mock it to reduce the overall test time, what should I do

This is the pseudo code of the bean of Mock：

```
public final class TimeoutBean implements InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware, ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        initProc();
    }

    /**
     * init
     */
    public void initProc() {
     //... Something time-consuming and irrelevant to this test
    }
}
```

And my mock unit test code：

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DelegateTo(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MockTest {

    @MockBean
    private TimeoutBean timeoutBean;
    @Resource
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void test() {
        doNothing().when(timeoutBean).initProc();
        myRepository.getById(1L);
    }

}
```

In this way, the Mock `initProc` method is invalid. I can probably understand because `@MockBean` calls after `InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet`. When the `afterPropertiesSet` is executed, `TimeoutBean` is not an Mock object, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `TimeoutBean` is final and mockito cannot mock final classes. So first you will have to fix that. After that I think it should work. For mocked classes you don't have to tell mockito to `doNothing()` becease that is the default behaviour for mocks.

I don't understand what you mean with: the Mock `initProc` method is invalid?

Comment: Yes, it is final, and the TimeoutBean is actually registered with Spring, not as a mockBean, so the initProc method must be actually executed as well. I was wondering if there was a way to tell Spring to launch the test with only a real load This test requires registered beans, and I can implement the rest entirely with mockBean, but for now it seems to bea one-by-one declaration, which is cumbersome